# GSheets filter by string from multiple items in a list

Tags: google-sheets

Good morning,

I am trying to filter one list (Website page URL and views) by multiple strings (unique ID contained in URL) contained in a second list, based on a condition (all pages, specific page or group of pages).

Summary = tab containing condition control (cell F17 - All / Group / specific page), unique ID (cell F18, populated when F17 set to specific page), and page group (G17)
DataPageViews = data sheet, column A full URL, column B page views
DataList = data sheet containing full URL and specific page slug for lookup (column P)
DataGroup = data sheet that dynamically updates based on Group selected on summary page with URL slug contained in D3:D.

I have no problem filtering the list by a single string from a second list (static or dynamic) using the REGEXMATCH:

but cannot get the filter to work on all strings for both the "All" condition or the "Group" condition

I have tried using various permutations of countif(), regexmatch() and arrayformula() but cannot get this to work.

The code looks like this - broken parts replaced with ...!

`=filter(DataPageViews!$A:$B,if(Summary!$F$17=DataList!$A$2,...,if(Summary!$F$17=DataList!$A$3,...,regexmatch(DataPageViews!$A:$A,Summary!$F$18))))```

1st removed part is trying to evaluate for all page URLs that contain all the page slugs from DataList tab (DataLists!P2:P)
2nd removed part is trying to evaluate for all page URLs that contain all the page slugs that appear in DataGroup dynamic list (DataGroup!D3:D)

Thank you!

UPDATED SOLUTION:

```
(if(F17=DataInnsList!$A$3,
  TEXTJOIN("|", 1, QUERY({DataInnsList!A2:P}, "select Col16 where Col10 = '"&G17&"'",)),
if(F17=DataInnsList!$A$2,
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, QUERY({DataInnsList!A2:P}, "select Col16 where Col5 != '"&F17&"'")),
if(not(or(F17=DataInnsList!$A$2,F17=DataInnsList!$A$3)),
 QUERY({DataInnsList!A2:P},"select Col16 where Col5 = '"&F17&"'"),"no data")
))),"no data")
```

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: Thank you player0 - a sample sheet can be seen here: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LRkMFflH6m4PLkelXt5Y83RgBzXp3GEv1EsRGxrEbhM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

try F18:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, QUERY({DataInnsList!A2:P}, "select Col16 where 1=1 "&
 IF(F17="",," and Col1  = '"&F17&"'")&
 IF(G17="",," and Col10 = '"&G17&"'"))), "no data")
```

and for pageviews:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(1*FILTER(DataPageViews!B:B, REGEXMATCH(DataPageViews!A:A, F18))), "no data")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, although unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Thank you for this, although unfortunately it does not work.  The formula in F18 returns the wrong value for a single site, and then only a single value for groups.  The filter pageviews then is not returning any data.  If it were possible on the filter view, it would be preferable to see all of the pages that makeup the sum, but understood if this is not possible!  Thank you for looking at this though, player0.

Comment: @Matt it was hard to tell whats your desired output and ruleset leading to your desired output so I just provided an example of how things can be done

Comment: Thank you @player0 p that is really really helpful.  I have solved it using your formula as the starting point